# Java Postgres connection limit exceeded

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am using Java 1.7 and Postgres via the Postgres JDBC drivers. The database connection will be used from a Web Service. In testing, I got the following error:

```
FATAL: connection limit exceeded for non-superusers
```

I solved the error by making my connection static, and, only creating once. My question is, is a static connection safe? Is this the right way to do this?

I am using the connection via a ConnectionFactory that looks something like this:

```
public class ConnectionFactory
{

   String driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver";
   String connectionUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbName";
   String dbUser = "user";
   String dbPwd = "password";
   private static ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = null;
   private static Connection conn = null;

   private ConnectionFactory()
   {
      try
      {
         Class.forName(driverClassName);
      }
      catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
   public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException
   {
      if (conn == null)
      {
         conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, dbUser, dbPwd);
      }
      return conn;
   }

   public static ConnectionFactory getInstance()
   {
      if (connectionFactory == null)
      {
         connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
      }
      return connectionFactory;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres JDBC driver is [documented as thread safe](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/thread.html) and the connection can be used by multiple threads if so required. If a thread attempts to use the connection while another one is using it, it will wait until the other thread has finished its current operation.

Connection pooling may be used anyway for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, original post didn't look at your code carefully.  Wow.  I still can't read.  Anyway, third time's the charm.  If your code is single threaded - then your fine.  If it's multi-threaded, use something like the Commons connection pools to manage your connections.  It looks like the driver is thread safe but the connection shouldn't be viewed as thread safe.  So, once the driver is loaded you can safely call getConnection on the driver from multiple threads, but the connection shouldn't be shared across threads.

Comment: I think this is incorrect. It appears the connection IS thread-safe, but, blocks.